# Multiple programs using the same class

Tags: c++, qt, class, static-libraries

I'm programming in Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010) in c++ and I'm trying to find out how to include the same class within 2 different programs.
I was trying to create a library MyLib with class A, but when I'm trying to create an instance of A, an "undefined reference" error occurs.

On my .pro file I added the following:

Libs += -L$$PWD/../build-MyLib-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/‌​release -lMyLib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MyLib/

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MyLib/

Is there any other way, maybe more common way, to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have a linker(?) error. Though you should really post the exact error message (and probably the related code and how you try to build it as well)

Comment: did you save your class-definition of `A` in a `.dll`-file or in a C/C++ header-file (`.h`)? I would suggest to use the header-file version

Comment: @Aemyl that would be a `.lib` file, since the question is tagged [static-libraries].

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. My errors are "Undefined reference to 'A::A()'" "Undefined reference to 'A::~A()'". I'm including the header file of the class. Although, if I create an instance of MyLib, it works fine

Comment: @Nitz you need to link the library file of MyLib to the project that uses the class. That's where your functions' definitions are.

Comment: @quentin I think I've already done that, tell me if I'm wrong. On my .pro file I added "Libs += -L$$PWD/../build-MyLib-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release -lMyLib" and also the INCLUDEPATH and DEPENDPATH statements

Comment: Please include this in your question, as well as as much relevant informations as possible. Forgetting to link the library file is a very common error, hence the shot in the dark, but there is no way we can *know* what is wrong with the question as it stands.